# How to convert text into ipa?

Tags: text-to-speech, phonetics

I want to convert some text into ipa to make sure the pronunciation will always be the same on all tts engines.

I didn't find a good way to do that, especially I need this for german.
I hoped for a service from a big player like Google, because of their advanced tts, but I didn't find one.

Does someone know a good tool / api / plugin for that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [espeak-ng](https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng/blob/master/src/espeak-ng.1.ronn), which does IPA output with the `-x` flag. There's also a couple of related libraries out there based on espeak/espeak-ng if you don't want to just use the CLI.

Also, Amazon Polly allows output of "visimes" (see [Speech Marks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/using-speechmarks.html), which in theory you could translate back into IPA (they have a [lookup table](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-polly-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/ref-phoneme-tables-shell.md)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Luke!  espeak-ng looks interesting. In contrast to sequitur g2p, which I tested the last days, it has a library. I will surely have a look at it! :D

Comment: I saw over Amazon Polly which also looked promising. Unfortunately, you can't translate back the visimes to ipa. 
Amazon: "In a language, each phoneme has a corresponding viseme that represents the shape that the mouth makes when forming the sound. However, not all visemes can be mapped to a particular phoneme because numerous phonemes appear the same when spoken, even though they sound different" (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/viseme.html)
It would have been nearly perfect if it had worked. It's a pity they don't return the phonemes also.